# Why are some measures separated by double lines?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I play piano. Sometimes, measures in pieces are separated by a double vertical line instead of a single one. What does this signify?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to indicating the end of a distinct section of the piece, a change in key signature, time signature or major tempo change, the double bar is also used to mark the location of a Da Capo or Dal Segno (a notation system that marks the repeating of a certain section of music without requiring additional measures to be written/printed.)

It is also used when a "fine" (end) of the piece appears in the middle of the piece.  These examples are described and illustrated on the following website:

http://piano.about.com/od/musicaltermsa1/g/GL_double-barline.htm

Comment: I think Stephen and Kristina and I are all correctly explaining the various uses of the double-bar line, so pay attention to all three of our answers!

Comment: I should also add that the beginning and end repeat signs (the thin and thick barline with the two dots on the inside) are in fact a special kind of double-bar lines in themselves.

Answer (score 4):

end of a section of music usually (such as chorus, verse, bridge, etc).

sometimes of a lengthy "phrase" of music.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what Stephen Hazel said, a double-line can also indicate an abrupt change in key, key signature, tempo, or time signature or metrical phrasing or a different rhythm. It is basically a cue to alert the musician that one section of the piece is ending and a new section that is substantially different is beginning.